# PHP - Uploading CSV, inserting to multiple tables and displaying elsewhere

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, csv

I'm trying to connect the dots for a few processes. I have a project that requires a CSV to be uploaded via form on webpage, which exists already, on a daily basis. Every time the CSV is loaded in the 110 columns need to be split into about 5 different MySQL tables. The CSV will always be in the same order, but I need to know exactly which variables/columns from the CSV to put into the specific tables and fields. Once this is done, I'll need to display the data on other pages, by query only (only some things will be displayed depending on the page). I have the following code to test putting the CSV into an array:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$array = $fields = array(); $i=0;
$file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($file, "r");

if($handle){
     while (($row = fgetcsv($handle, 4096)) !== false) {
    if (empty($fields)) {
        $fields = $row;
        continue;
    }
    foreach ($row as $k=>$value) {
        $array[$i][$fields[$k]] = $value;
    }
    $i++;

}

echo "Success!";
var_dump($array);
if (!feof($handle)) {
    echo "Error: unexpected fgets() fail\n";
}
fclose($handle);
}}?>
```

This seems to work fine with the Var_dump. Then, separately, I've used the following code on a small CSV with only ten fields:

```
while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 4096, ",")) !== false)
{

 $one = $filesop[0];
 $two = $filesop[1];
 $three = $filesop[2];
 $four = $filesop[3];
 $five = $filesop[4];
 $six = $filesop[5];
 $seven = $filesop[6];
 $eight = $filesop[7];
 $nine = $filesop[8];
 $ten = $filesop[9];

 $sql = "INSERT INTO staging (One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten) VALUES ('$one','$two', '$three','$four','$five','$six','$seven','$eight','$nine','$ten')";

 }

 if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
 echo "You database has imported successfully";
 } else {
 echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error; 
 }
```

I'm still confused on how I can map the 110 fields of these daily uploaded CSV to their correct tables (10 fields into one table, 25 into another, 30 into another, etc. ) so that I can use the variables to display certain fields on other pages.

UPDATE:

New code for arrays:

```
$table_cols[5] ="workOrderNum,lowSideMIUNum,highSideMIUNum,accountNum,custName,address,locID,utility,serialNumber,serviceName";



$tablenames = array("staging","clients","meters","tests","costs","workorders");

for($tableno = 0;$tableno < sizeof($tablenames);$tableno++){
$q = "";
$q .= "INSERT INTO ".$tablenames[$tableno]." (".$table_cols[$tableno].") VALUES (";
$cols = explode("," ,$table_cols);
$data = array();
foreach($col as $key => $fldname) {
    $data[] = "'".$coldata[$fldname]."'";
}

$q .= implode(",",$data).");";

}
echo'File submitted';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**See Update Below** *This part of the answer left for context*

You could create an array with indexes of the columns to be saved in each table. Then run one insert per table, getting the column values based on the index in your array for that table.

```
$tbl1_idxs = array(1,4,10,20,15,22);
$tbl2_idxs = array(2,9,1,7,32,44);
$tbl3_idxs = array(27,15,65,110,12);

$q1 = "";
$q1 .= "INSERT INTO `Table1` (`fld1`,`fld2`,`fld3`,`fld4`,`fld5`,`fld6`) ";
$q1 .= "VALUES ('";
$q1 .= $filesop[tbl1_idxs[0]]."','";
$q1 .= $filesop[tbl1_idxs[1]]."','";
$q1 .= $filesop[tbl1_idxs[2]]."','";
$q1 .= $filesop[tbl1_idxs[3]]."','";
$q1 .= $filesop[tbl1_idxs[4]]."','";
$q1 .= $filesop[tbl1_idxs[5]]."');";

//  Execute query #1....

$q2 = "";
$q2 .= "INSERT INTO `Table2` (`fld1`,`fld2`,`fld3`,`fld4`,`fld5`,`fld6`) ";
$q2 .= "VALUES ('";
$q2 .= $filesop[tbl2_idxs[0]]."','";
$q2 .= $filesop[tbl2_idxs[1]]."','";
$q2 .= $filesop[tbl2_idxs[2]]."','";
$q2 .= $filesop[tbl2_idxs[3]]."','";
$q2 .= $filesop[tbl2_idxs[4]]."','";
$q2 .= $filesop[tbl2_idxs[5]]."');";

//  Execute query #2....

$q3 = "";
$q3 .= "INSERT INTO `Table3` (`fld1`,`fld2`,`fld3`,`fld4`,`fld5`,`fld6`) ";
$q3 .= "VALUES ('";
$q3 .= $filesop[tbl3_idxs[0]]."','";
$q3 .= $filesop[tbl3_idxs[1]]."','";
$q3 .= $filesop[tbl3_idxs[2]]."','";
$q3 .= $filesop[tbl3_idxs[3]]."','";
$q3 .= $filesop[tbl3_idxs[4]]."','";
$q3 .= $filesop[tbl3_idxs[5]]."');";

//  Execute query #3....
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

With that many columns, I would map by column name instead. There are several ways this could be made manageable.

In any case, instead of hard variable names for each column of the CSV, I would put them in an associative array, with the keys matching the column names of the tables. You could then have a comma separated list of columns for each table.

You would still have the 203 lines of code to map the CSV fields to names, but maintaining which column goes into which table would at least be readable. And changing the existing code that assigned each CSV column to a variable should be a simple regex search and replace.

```
$coldata = array();
$coldata['name'] = $filesop[0];
$coldata['addr1'] = $filesop[1];
$coldata['addr2'] = $filesop[2];
$coldata['city'] = $filesop[3];
$coldata['state'] = $filesop[4];
$coldata['zip'] = $filesop[5];
$coldata['country'] = $filesop[6];
$coldata['gender'] = $filesop[7];
$coldata['age'] = $filesop[8];
$coldata['birthdate'] = $filesop[9];

$table_cols = array();

$table_cols[0] = "name,gender,age";
$table_cols[1] = "name,addr1,addr2,city,state,zip";
$table_cols[2] = "name,age,birthdate";

$tablenames = array("staging","info","other");

for($tableno = 0;$tableno < sizeof($tablenames);$tableno++) {
    $q = "";
    $q .= "INSERT INTO ".$tablenames[$tableno]." (".$table_cols[$tableno].") VALUES (";
    $cols = explode(",",$table_cols[$tableno]);
    $data = array();
    foreach($col as $key => $fldname) {
        $data[] = "'".$coldata[$fldname]."'";
    }
    $q .= implode(",",$data).");";

    //    Execute query in $q

}
```

Comment: Ah, I haven't seen that method yet. So question: We created a php file for reference, in case we needed a variable for every single column. Basically it has 203 lines where I've created a variable ($accountNum, $client, $etc.) for every column of the CSV. This is obviously a lengthy and agonizing way to do it, but it gives us full control of every variable. You're saying I would assocaite every column of the CSV (203) with an array index and then spend my time mapping the index numbers to the correct position in the tables I already have created?

Comment: I was just looking over this again and had a few quick questions: First, the coldata array would be about 203 lines long right? Just one long array for every single column? And then, each table_cols array index would be for the 7 tables, so there would be 7 lines there ([0]-[6]) holding all respective names?

Comment: @H.Norman: Regarding the table_cols array, that's right. With the updated example, you're still mapping one variable for each column, but since it's in an array it gives you the added advantage of being able to loop through or index to a particular column value. If your CSV has column names in the first line, you can make that part automatic.

Comment: Thank you, that's making more since now. I updated my code above with the snippet you gave me and I've filled in the table names. I created 203 variables and inserted them into the table columns array and after running a test of this by uploading a CSV I get my successful connection message as well as my successful insert message, but my database is still empty. For instance, I have a staging table that only has one column for primary key. Would I have to create each field in the database table in MySQL workbench? or should this insert them regardless?

Comment: The table must have a column defined for you to insert data into it, so yes, you have to define the columns in each table. If you match the column names in the tables to the column names used in the CSV, you could construct the INSERT statement based on the table_cols array info. That way, if your CSV changes or your table definitions change (i.e. new/deleted columns), you would only need to update the array declarations.

Comment: I actually removed the headers from the CSV so I'm not sure if they will be on the final copies or not. For now I will just create columns in the database that match my fields in the PHP code and take it from there.

Comment: I actually got the $filesop variable defined correctly, but I'm getting errors on explode and foreach, where explode expects the 2nd parameter to be a string and invalid argument on foreach. I'm not sure how that's incorrect though.

Comment: @H.Normal: Are you referring to the line: $cols = explode(",",$table_cols[$tableno]); and the foreach 2 lines below that? IOW, is that where you are seeing the errors?

Comment: That's right. It's saying that the 2nd parameter in explode should be a string and that the argument for foreach is invalid. I'm wondering if it has to do with the PHP syntax error I also get upon upload of my CSV for the table_cols. I currently have table_cols[0]=",,,,," with all values in one set of quotes. Should each value have it's own set of quotes there?

Comment: It looks like I may have fixed the explode argument with the [$tableno] variable which fixed the foreach invalid argument. Just getting the syntax error now, still with no insertion into the db table

Comment: Yes, table_cols[0] = 'fld1,fld2' is correct. It should be a string in order for the explode to work.  What code is generating the syntax error?

Comment: This is the error i get:

success!Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'null,workOrderNum,lowSideMIUNum,highSideMIUNum,accountNum,custName,address,locID' at line 1

And the code (small snippet since there are 200 of these): $table_cols[0] = "orderNumber,null,workOrderNum,lowSideMIUNum,highSideMIUNum

Comment: Sounds like you have a double comma somewhere in one of your column lists.

Comment: Ok, I'm assuming that would be within the quotes on my large table_cols[0] block. I'm scanning through now

Comment: I posted on your other thread for this issue. Basically, your column name list should only have the columns used for that table. Do not put placeholders for (ie. null) for columns not saved to that table.

Comment: Thank you, the issue is that they have the 2nd column in the table as null, as well as the 2nd header in the CSV, but I changed it to 'place' since the headers are deleted anyway. That syntax error then populated for another place further down the line in the block of code. Still checking through for a double comma though. I also did a var_dump on the query and it shows the entirety of the statement in the dump

Comment: If the column isn't to be written to, leave it out of the list of columns. Even if the table has additional columns not in the CSV, or columns in the CSV not in the table. List only those columns for the particular table that need to be saved.

Comment: Ok, I removed it from the table_col array and the column list, though it remains in the db table. Now the error has changed to a new section of variables within the table_col array. I'm using the 'staging' table to store the whole CSV and once that works I'll split things from there, that's why there are so many variables in the table_col list

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139189/discussion-between-sloan-thrasher-and-h-norman).